# Passing a function as an argument - lambda expression error?

Tags: function, functional-programming, lisp, parameter-passing, common-lisp

I am trying to create a function that accepts a list and a function as parameters and applies that function to each element in the List.
Here is my attempt:

```
(defun filter(fn L)
  (if (eq 0 (length L))
      (print "list empty")
      (print (mapcar (lambda (n) (#'fn n)) L))))
(print (filter #'evenp '(1 2 2 3 4)))
```

here is a second attempt:

```
(defvar R nil)
(defun filter(fn L)
  (if (eq 0 (length L))
      nil
      (cons (R (funcall fn (car L)) filter(fn (cdr L))))))
(print(filter #'evenp '(1 2 2 3 4)))
```

But for some simply confusing and unexplainable reason, 
I get following error for the first one:

```
#'FN should be lambda expression.
```

and this one for the second:

```
Undefined function R
```

I have tried so many things but nothing has worked so far.

Edit::
Thank you for the help so far. This:

```
(defun filter(fn L)
  (if (eq 0 (length L))
      (print "list empty")
      (remove-if-not #'fn '(1 2 3 4 5))))

(print (filter #'evenp '(1 2 2 3 4)))
```

This should do it. But I am still getting the

```
Undefined function FN
```

error. What to do???

Comment: Shouldn't `filter(fn (cdr L))` be `(filter fn (cdr L))`?

Answer (score 9):

## How to do what you want

`filter` is called [`remove-if-not`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm)
in Common Lisp:

```
(remove-if-not #'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5))
==> (2 4)
```

## What is wrong with your code - syntactically

### First Attempt

When you try to call a function stored in a variable (or passed into a
function as a parameter), you need to
use [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm)
or [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm):

```
(mapcar (lambda (n) (funcall #'fn n)) L)
```

or just pass it along
to [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm):

```
(mapcar fn L)
```

### Second Attempt

This is a total mess.
You need to learn Common Lisp syntax, there are many nice books (see
[want to learn common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7446884/850781)).

The specific problem is that `R` is in a function position (first list
element) but it is not defined as a function - it is a variable.
Even if you fix this problem, there are more problems there.
You should read a book and then work it out yourself, it will be a
useful exercise.

Basically, in Common Lisp parentheses are [*meaningful*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46224551/850781).
E.g., in C you can write `x+y`, `(x+y)`, `(x)+(y)` &c and they all mean
the same.
In Common Lisp `R`, `(R)`, `((R))` &c are very different.

### Third Attempt ("edit")

```
(defun filter(fn L)
  (if (eq 0 (length L))
      (print "list empty")
      (remove-if-not #'fn '(1 2 3 4 5))))
```

Here you have a *variable* `fn`, but you are using it as if it were a *function* (`#'fn`).

You need to do

```
      (remove-if-not fn '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

instead.

## What is wrong with your code - semantically

### No need for `print`

First, [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) is virtually
*never* the right function to use in code. Use `princ`, `prin1` or
`write` instead.

Second, [Common Lisp REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15708911/850781)
stands for Read-Eval-***Print*** Loop, so you do NOT need to print the
return value of your function explicitly.

### Follow the coding conventions

You write your code for others (including yourself 6 months down the road) to *read*, not just for a computer to *run*.
If you follow the conventions, including naming your variables and functions,
parentheses placement, indentation &c, you make your code more readable.

#### Compare with 0 using [`zerop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_zerop.htm)

Write `(zerop X)` instead of `(eq 0 X)` (actually, you should
use [`eql`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/a_eql.htm) for numbers, but this is
getting too hairy for now).

#### [`length`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_length.htm) can be expensive

Do not scan the whole list if all you need to know is whether it is
empty.
IOW,

```
(if (zero (length l))
    (print "the list is empty")
    (mapcar ... l))
```

is better written as

```
(if (null l)
    (print "the list is empty")
    (mapcar ... l))
```

Answer (score 2):

> #'FN should be lambda expression.

You've got **(fn (cdr L))** in your code, and **fn** can't be called like that.  Just like earlier in that line, you need to do **(filter fn (cdr L))**, not **filter(fn (cdr L))**.

> Undefined function R

Same thing here.  You've got **(cons (R ...))** where you're trying to call **R** as a function, but it's not.  It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do with **R**, so I can't really offer any help there.