# Lisp, instructions not working in defun

Tags: syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to make a function that changes infix input to prefix eg : `(x + 1)` as input outputted as `(+ x 1)`.

So here is my code for the moment :

```
(setq x '(Y + 1))
(if (listp x ) (list (second x) (first x) (first (last x))) x)
```

so it returns `(+ Y 1)` if I input a list and the user input if it's not a list.

However, the problem is that I can't get this code working in a function :

```
(defun prefixToInfix (x)(
   (if (listp x ) (list (second x) (first x) (first (last x))) x)
   )
 )
```

the function is indeed created but when I call it

```
(prefixtoinfix '(Y + 1))
```

I get an error

```
Error: Illegal function object: (IF (LISTP X) (LIST # # #) X).
[condition type: TYPE-ERROR]
```

I don't know why my if statement works in the main program but doesn't when I run it from my function.

Comment: You have extra parentheses around the function body.

Comment: what do you mean ? Can you correct it ?

Comment: Remove the opening paren from the end of the first line `(x)(` -> `(x)`, and the last closing paren.

Comment: Thanks ! it took me so much time to find out

Answer (score 5):

What you are missing is that in Lisp parentheses are *meaningful*.

In C/Java/Python &c, the following expressions are the same:

```
a+b
(a+b)
(a)+(b)
(((a)+(b)))
(((((a)+(b)))))
```

In Lisp, the following expressions are very different:

- `a` --- a symbol
- `(a)` --- a list with a single element, which is the symbol `a`
- `(1 (2))` --- a list of two elements:

  1. number `1`
  2. list of of length 1, containing number `2`

In your case, function (note indentation and paren placement!)

```
(defun prefixToInfix (x)
  ((if (listp x) (list (second x) (first x) (first (last x))) x)))
```

has extra parens around `if` (and this causes the whole `if` form to be interpreted as a function, with disastrous results), and should be (note line breaks and indentation - lispers do not count parens, they look at indentation to understand the code, see http://lisp-lang.org/style-guide/)

```
(defun prefix-to-infix (x)
  (if (listp x)
      (list (second x)
            (first x)
            (first (last x)))
      x))
```

PS. See also recommendations in [want to learn common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7446884/850781).