# Read the proper input to a variable

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I would like to have a variable containing an `integer`, that came from an input of a user. It can't accept strings neither decimal numbers.

I would like some help to understand what I am doing wrong here.

My code until now:

I appreciate the help.

```
(format t "~%Enter a number: ")
(loop (defvar numb (read))
(cond (((rationalp numb)1)
        (print "No decimal numbers are allowed, please enter an integer"))
      (((stringp numb)1)
        (print "No strings are allowed, please enter an integer"))
)
(when ((integerp numb)1) (return numb))
)
```

Comment: You might find this link helpful http://gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html. There are some useful routines there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Working code

Here is how I would do it:

```
(defun ask-and-read (prompt)
  "Prompt the user and read his input."
  (princ prompt *query-io*)
  (force-output *query-io*)  ; flush the buffers
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))   ; close the security hole
    (read *query-io*)))

(defun request-object (prompt predicate)
  "Ask the user for an object using prompt.
Only accept data which satisfies the predicate."
  (loop
    for object = (ask-and-read prompt)
    when (funcall predicate object)
    return object
    do (format *query-io* "Alas, ~S (~S) does not satisfy ~S, please try again~%"
               object (type-of object) predicate)))
```

Example:

```
> (request-object "Enter an integer: " #'integerp)
Enter an integer: 4.6
Alas, 4.6 (SINGLE-FLOAT) does not satisfy #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION INTEGERP>, please try again
Enter an integer: 5/7
Alas, 5/7 (RATIO) does not satisfy #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION INTEGERP>, please try again
Enter an integer: asdf
Alas, ASDF (SYMBOL) does not satisfy #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION INTEGERP>, please try again
Enter an integer: 7
==> 7
> (request-object "Enter a real: " #'realp)
Enter a real: 4.5
==> 4.5
> (request-object "Enter a real: " #'realp)
Enter a real: 5/8
==> 5/8
> (request-object "Enter a real: " #'realp)
Enter a real: "sdf"
Alas, "sdf" ((SIMPLE-BASE-STRING 3)) does not satisfy #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION REALP>, please try again
Enter a real: 8
==> 8
```

Please see the documentation for the facilities I used:

- [`princ`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm)
- [`force-output`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm)
- [`*query-io*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_debug_.htm)
- [`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm)
- [`*read-eval*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_rd_eva.htm)
- [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm):

  - [`for`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abad.htm)
  - [`when`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_af.htm)
  - [`return`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_aga.htm)
  - [`do`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ae.htm)
- [`format`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_c.htm)

## Your mistakes

### Code formatting

Your code is unreadable because you have incorrect indentation.
Lispers do not count parens - this is the job for compilers and editors.
We look at *indentation*.
Please do yourself a favor and use Emacs - it will indent the code for you and you will often see your errors yourself.

### Defvar is a top-level form

First of all, [`defvar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) is a top-level form which is used to *define* global variables, not set them.
Subsequent calls do *not* change the value:

```
(defvar *abc* 1)
*abc*
==> 1
(defvar *abc* 10)
*abc*
==> 1   ; not 10!
```

Use [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm) to set variable.

### Prefer local variables to global variables

While Lisp does allow global variables, the predominant programming
style in Lisp is the functional style: every function receives its
"input" data as arguments and returns its "output" data as values. 
To achieve functional style, prefer a local to a global variable. 
You create local variables through [`let` or
`let*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) or, in `loop`, see
[Local Variable Initializations](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abb.htm).

### Cond and When have very specific syntax

You have extra parens and `1`(?!) in your [`cond`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm) and [`when`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_when_.htm) forms.

Remember, [parens are meaningful in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46224551/850781).

### Security first!

Binding [`*read-eval*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_rd_eva.htm) to `nil`
before [`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) is necessary to
avoid a nuclear war if a user enters `#.(launch-nuclear-missiles)`
in response to your prompt, because normally `read` evaluates whatever
comes after [`#.`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhf.htm).

Comment: thanks a lot. Very well explained. Yes, after asking here I kept trying and I figured that this 1 was wrong. I thought that somehow it was needed in order to match with a true statement. I was wrong lol  Thanks again

Comment: Note that you need FINISH-OUTPUT after printing a prompt in portable CL.

Comment: One might want to use `*query-io*` for such prompts.