# Lisp: create random odd numbers

Tags: common-lisp

I've got this:

```
(let ((num 1))
  (mapcar (lambda (x)
            (cons x (if (evenp (setf num (random 299)))
                        (1+ num)
                        (num))))
          '(a b c d e f)))
```

which should produce something like this:

```
 ((A . 37) (B . 283) (C . 232) (D . 251) (E . 273) (F . 170)
```

only with odd numbers. Yes, very kludgy looking. Is there something with `random-state` that would help? Or the "hidden system variable" that holds onto that initial `random` calculation? Here's a global function I tried:

```
(defun random-odd ()
  (let ((num 0))
    (if (evenp (setf num (random 299)))
        (1+ num)
      (num))))
```

Also not working. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you want something like this: f() => rand() * 2 + 1

Comment: Why would you need SETF in your function?

Comment: What is `(num)` supposed to do?

Comment: Please copy and paster the full error message instead of saying "_not working_".

Comment: Yes, the `rand() * 2 + 1` is the mathematician's touch. Right, `(num)` was completely dumb of me. Will also be more error-verbose next time.

Answer (score 5):

Your `random-odd` is almost fine except for the style and using `num` in
the function position (remember, [Lisp parentheses are *meaningful*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46224551/850781)):

```
(defun random-odd ()
  (let ((num (random 299)))
    (if (evenp num)
        (1+ num)
        num)))
```

The *subtle* problem with this function is that the probability of getting 299 is *half* the probability of getting any other odd number from 1 to 297.

This is because [`(random 299)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_random.htm) returns numbers from 0 to 298 inclusive with equal probability 1/299. Thus `random-odd` will return, say, 17 with probability 2/299 (if `random` returns 17 or 16) but it will return 299 with probability 1/299 (if `random` returns 298).

Thus I would suggest

```
(defun random-odd (even-limit)
  "Return an odd random number from 0 to EVEN-LIMIT, exclusive."
  (assert (evenp even-limit) (even-limit)
          "~S: ~S must be even" 'random-odd 'even-limit)
  (let ((num (random even-limit)))
    (if (evenp num)
        (1+ num)
        num)))
```

A completely equivalent approach would be

```
(defun random-odd (half-limit)
  "Return a random odd number from 1 to half-limit*2-1 inclusive."
  (1+ (ash (random half-limit) 1)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to (1+ (* 2 (random 150)))? My statistics knowledge is a bit weak though.

Comment: To clarify, seems like ×2+1 avoids a lot of unnecessary computation without sacrificing much, if any, clarity, but I'm uncertain if it would subtly seem the results somehow.

Comment: The outcome, but unless someone has better optimizers than I expect, I'd think the compare and branch-or-increment would add some overhead. Probably trivial compared to the cons, but /shrug.

Comment: @BRFennPocock but you have to compute half-limit instead of the actual limit ;-)

Comment: sure, but every optimizer can do a ÷2 = Ash -1, and that's outside the loop. I know, I deal in tighter margins than most people care to, but /shrug … Define-Compiler-Macro is always there, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (x)
    (let ((num (random 299)))
      (cons x (if (evenp num)
          (1+ num)
        num))))
'(a b c d e f))
```

Comment: Thanks karsten, this is what I went with, embedding it in a `flet`. Forgot you could put a `let` inside a `mapcar`.