# if statement within loop for statement in lisp

Tags: syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp

I'm getting an error trying to do the if statement within the loop for statement.  Is it possible to put an if statement here?

```
(princ "Enter a number: ")

(setq number(read))

(setq number (- number 1))

(setq primechecker nil)

(loop for x from 2 to number 
   do ((if (> x 5)(princ 5)(princ x))))
```

Comment: [parens are meaningful in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46223692/850781)

Comment: You're trying to call `princ`'s return value as a function.

Comment: @molbdnilo And even when you have a function `f` where `(f)` returns a function, `((f))` is not valid Common Lisp. You'd need `(funcall (f))`.

Comment: @coredump Ah, yes. Every time I Lisp, I stumble on that one.