# Lisp - replace all the appereances of an element in a list

Tags: syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp

I try to replace a certain element E in a list with another list K at all the main list levels.

```
(defun replaceList(l e k)
  (cond
    ((null l) nil)
    ((equal e (car l)) (cons k (replaceList (cdr l) e k)))
    ((listp (car l))
     ((equal e (car (car l))) (cons k (replaceList (cdr (car l)) e k))))
    (t (cons (car l) (replaceList (cdr l) e k)))))
```

Example:

```
(replaceList '(3 1 2 (6 1) 7 (5 (5 (3 1))) 9) '1 '(99 99))
--> (3 (99 99) 2 (6 (99 99)) 7 (5 (5 (3 (99 99) ) ) ) 9)
```

I get something with lambda expression as error message.

Also,i tried instead of the `listp(car l)` "block" :
`((listp (car l)) (cons k (replaceList (cdr (car l)) e k)))`.
I get something weird :
`(2 1 3 ( 6 1 7) 7 1 2 )` -> `(2 (99 99) 3 (99 99) (99 99) 7)`

Comment: "I get something with lambda expression as error message" -- please copy and paste the exact error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Error

Your "lambda expression message" is due to an extra set of parens around `equal` in the `listp` clause. Remember, [Lisp parentheses are *meaningful*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46223692/850781).

## Use the standard library!

ANSI Common Lisp has [`subst`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_substc.htm) which does what you want:

```
(subst '(99 99) 1 '(3 1 2 (6 1) 7 (5 (5 (3 1))) 9) :test #'equal)
==> (3 (99 99) 2 (6 (99 99)) 7 (5 (5 (3 (99 99)))) 9)
```

## Your algorithm

Since you are operating on the *tree*, not *list* (you say "*all the
main list levels*"), you should treat `car` and `cdr` identically:

```
(defun my-subst (new old tree &key (test #'eql))
  (cond ((funcall test old tree)
         new)
        ((atom tree)
         tree)
        (t
         (cons (my-subst new old (car tree) :test test)
               (my-subst new old (cdr tree) :test test)))))
(my-subst '(99 99) 1 '(3 1 2 (6 1) 7 (5 (5 (3 1))) 9) :test #'equal)
==> (3 (99 99) 2 (6 (99 99)) 7 (5 (5 (3 (99 99)))) 9)
```

Or, simplified (without [`&key`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_dad.htm) and
[`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm)):

```
(defun my-subst (new old tree)
  (cond ((equal old tree)
         new)
        ((atom tree)
         tree)
        (t
         (cons (my-subst new old (car tree))
               (my-subst new old (cdr tree))))))
```

Comment: Hello,@sds. Thank you for your answer.But there is not any possible modification to my code to make it work? Our professor insisted to not work with standard library functions like 'subst'( yes,i know,it's a little bit weird,but i think she wants to make us understand the algorithm behind this......).Thank you for the helping links also :)

Comment: @EduardAdrian: isn't `my-subst` what you are looking for? You can change the order of arguments, of course. Let me reiterate: if you are not using `car` and `cdr` symmetrically, you are not doing the right thing.

Comment: It might be,but i don't understand the &key (test #'eql) and funcall structure. We are at a very basic level,i think we will learn about that later. That's why i asked for a very simplistic way of solving the exercise.

Comment: @EduardAdrian: I added a simplified version.