# My function doesn't work. I get this error: define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm new to programming and I'm learning the Scheme language using DrRacket  version 7.5. I'm trying to create a function which takes in a number. The number should then be added to a value that is one number less than the one selected until it reaches 0. I believe I am trying to create an example of recursion.

```lisp
(define (add-lesser-numbers num)
  (if(>= num 0))
     (+(num(- num 1)))
      )
```

Comment: This is not lisp but scheme. Please tell us what software you are using, including version numbers.

Comment: I'm using DrRacket. I believe It's the 7.5 version

Comment: If the function were recursive, you would see its own name used in its definition. You want something of the form `(if (> num 0) recursion base-case)`. (Note that an `if` conditional must have both branches. DrRacket has an excellent documentation system; use it.)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious glitch in your code is extra parentheses:

```lisp
(define (add-lesser-numbers num)
  (if (>= num 0)
      (+ num (- num 1))
      (+ num 42)))
```

Remember, [parens in lisp and scheme are meaningful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46224551/850781).

Comment: After removing the paren, I get this error message, "if: expected a question and two answers, but found only 2 parts"

Comment: @jjcode367: you had more than 1 extra paren. My code works, please try it.

Comment: I used your code and I get that error. Could it be the something with the setting in my DrRacket?

Comment: I guess DrRacket requires _both_ alternatives for `if` - try the new version

Comment: "expected a question and two answers"? This must be some toy for teaching toddlers. The three parts of a conditional are called *antecedent*, *consequent* and *alternative*.